# How can I remove object from multidimensional array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, vuex, store

My case is bit different from other cases.

I have an object that contains an array like this:

```js
var doctors = {
  '2bf169c6-bc51-4dc6-1234-cf81e611b6fd': [
    {
      doctor_id: "2bf169c6-bc51-4dc6-1234-cf81e611b6fd",
      name: "dr. Benjamin",
      specialization_id: "5f8e2525-65fa-4a92-2312-fcd0323ad439",
      specialization_name: "General practitioners",
      hospital_id: "63c6af56-bb9a-4962-6677-454d3345630d",
      hospital_name: "Hospital A"
    }
  ],
  'd8e31868-ebec-4af0-4321-767aa696f91a': [
    {
      doctor_id: "d8e31868-ebec-4af0-4321-767aa696f91a",
      name: "dr. Theo",
      specialization_id: "329de195-1ab6-4a43-3322-acfde447fec3",
      specialization_name: "Internal Medicine",
      hospital_id: "39764039-37b9-4176-4455-ef7b2e124ba4",
      hospital_name: "Hospital B"
    },
    {
      doctor_id: "d8e31868-ebec-4af0-4321-767aa696f91a",
      name: "dr. Theo",
      specialization_id: "329de195-1ab6-4a43-3322-acfde447fec3",
      specialization_name: "Internal Medicine",
      hospital_id: "65a60870-beab-4925-3322-4a5246e26d6a",
      hospital_name: "Hospital C"
    }
  ], 
  '0a24e765-3e3c-45e6-1122-8671eb3c0439': [
    {
      doctor_id: "0a24e765-3e3c-45e6-1122-8671eb3c0439",
      name: "dr. John",
      specialization_id: "5f8e2525-65fa-4a92-2312-fcd0323ad439",
      specialization_name: "General practitioners",
      hospital_id: "153b75ee-dc07-4290-2121-d4d28457780f",
      hospital_name: "Hospital D",
    },
    {
      doctor_id: "0a24e765-3e3c-45e6-1122-8671eb3c0439",
      name: "dr. John",
      specialization_id: "5f8e2525-65fa-4a92-2312-fcd0323ad439",
      specialization_name: "General practitioners",
      hospital_id: "153b75ee-dc07-4290-2121-d4d28457780f",
      hospital_name: "Hospital E",
    }
  ],
  '4990a698-afba-483b-5544-ecc5201e45c3': [
    {
      doctor_id: "4990a698-afba-483b-5544-ecc5201e45c3",
      name: "dr. Frank",
      specialization_id: "97ce4804-6508-4d65-dd33-70a3d14604ae",
      specialization_name: "Neurologist",
      hospital_id: "c279e92e-57c3-47ad-5656-397b4fe8b6f7",
      hospital_name: "Hospital F",
    }
  ]
};
```

I want to add the `isExistSchedule` key to the array. `isExistSchedule` key` is obtained from VueX Store.

---

This is my code:

```js
const newDoctors = {}
for (let item in doctors) {
  for (let i = 0; i < doctors[item].length; i++) {
    const paramsSchedule = {
      hospitalId: doctors[item][i].hospital_id,
      doctorId: doctors[item][i].doctor_id
    }
    const promiseSchedule = this.getDataSchedule(paramsSchedule) // call VueX store and API
    await promiseSchedule
    const dataSchedule = this.dataSchedule.items
    doctors[item][i].isExistSchedule = dataSchedule.isExistSchedule
  }
  newDoctors[item] = doctors[item]
}
```

To provide an example, here is `isExistSchedule` hardcoded for each item:

```js
doctors['2bf169c6-bc51-4dc6-1234-cf81e611b6fd'][0].isExistSchedule = false
doctors['d8e31868-ebec-4af0-4321-767aa696f91a'][0].isExistSchedule = true
doctors['d8e31868-ebec-4af0-4321-767aa696f91a'][1].isExistSchedule = false
doctors['0a24e765-3e3c-45e6-1122-8671eb3c0439'][0].isExistSchedule = true
doctors['0a24e765-3e3c-45e6-1122-8671eb3c0439'][1].isExistSchedule = true
doctors['4990a698-afba-483b-5544-ecc5201e45c3'][0].isExistSchedule = true
```

---

I want to delete elements in the group when `isExistSchedule = false`. I also want to remove the parent when there are no more items.

So I want the final result to be like this:

```js
var doctors = {
  'd8e31868-ebec-4af0-4321-767aa696f91a': [
    {
      doctor_id: "d8e31868-ebec-4af0-4321-767aa696f91a",
      name: "dr. Theo",
      specialization_id: "329de195-1ab6-4a43-3322-acfde447fec3",
      specialization_name: "Internal Medicine",
      hospital_id: "39764039-37b9-4176-4455-ef7b2e124ba4",
      hospital_name: "Hospital B"
    },
  ], 
  '0a24e765-3e3c-45e6-1122-8671eb3c0439': [
    {
      doctor_id: "0a24e765-3e3c-45e6-1122-8671eb3c0439",
      name: "dr. John",
      specialization_id: "5f8e2525-65fa-4a92-2312-fcd0323ad439",
      specialization_name: "General practitioners",
      hospital_id: "153b75ee-dc07-4290-2121-d4d28457780f",
      hospital_name: "Hospital D",
    },
    {
      doctor_id: "0a24e765-3e3c-45e6-1122-8671eb3c0439",
      name: "dr. John",
      specialization_id: "5f8e2525-65fa-4a92-2312-fcd0323ad439",
      specialization_name: "General practitioners",
      hospital_id: "153b75ee-dc07-4290-2121-d4d28457780f",
      hospital_name: "Hospital E",
    }
  ],
  '4990a698-afba-483b-5544-ecc5201e45c3': [
    {
      doctor_id: "4990a698-afba-483b-5544-ecc5201e45c3",
      name: "dr. Frank",
      specialization_id: "97ce4804-6508-4d65-dd33-70a3d14604ae",
      specialization_name: "Neurologist",
      hospital_id: "c279e92e-57c3-47ad-5656-397b4fe8b6f7",
      hospital_name: "Hospital F",
    }
  ]
};
```

How do I make the code so the result look like that?

I have tried it, but I am not able to achieve this result.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Array.prototype.filter` to filter out the elements

```js
let doctors = {
  '2bf169c6-bc51-4dc6-1234-cf81e611b6fd': [
    {
      doctor_id: '2bf169c6-bc51-4dc6-1234-cf81e611b6fd',
      name: 'dr. Benjamin',
      specialization_id: '5f8e2525-65fa-4a92-2312-fcd0323ad439',
      specialization_name: 'General practitioners',
      hospital_id: '63c6af56-bb9a-4962-6677-454d3345630d',
      hospital_name: 'Hospital A',
      isExistSchedule: false
    }
  ],
  'd8e31868-ebec-4af0-4321-767aa696f91a': [
    {
      doctor_id: 'd8e31868-ebec-4af0-4321-767aa696f91a',
      name: 'dr. Theo',
      specialization_id: '329de195-1ab6-4a43-3322-acfde447fec3',
      specialization_name: 'Internal Medicine',
      hospital_id: '39764039-37b9-4176-4455-ef7b2e124ba4',
      hospital_name: 'Hospital B',
      isExistSchedule: true
    },
    {
      doctor_id: 'd8e31868-ebec-4af0-4321-767aa696f91a',
      name: 'dr. Theo',
      specialization_id: '329de195-1ab6-4a43-3322-acfde447fec3',
      specialization_name: 'Internal Medicine',
      hospital_id: '65a60870-beab-4925-3322-4a5246e26d6a',
      hospital_name: 'Hospital C',
      isExistSchedule: false
    }
  ],
  '0a24e765-3e3c-45e6-1122-8671eb3c0439': [
    {
      doctor_id: '0a24e765-3e3c-45e6-1122-8671eb3c0439',
      name: 'dr. John',
      specialization_id: '5f8e2525-65fa-4a92-2312-fcd0323ad439',
      specialization_name: 'General practitioners',
      hospital_id: '153b75ee-dc07-4290-2121-d4d28457780f',
      hospital_name: 'Hospital D',
      isExistSchedule: true
    },
    {
      doctor_id: '0a24e765-3e3c-45e6-1122-8671eb3c0439',
      name: 'dr. John',
      specialization_id: '5f8e2525-65fa-4a92-2312-fcd0323ad439',
      specialization_name: 'General practitioners',
      hospital_id: '153b75ee-dc07-4290-2121-d4d28457780f',
      hospital_name: 'Hospital E',
      isExistSchedule: true
    }
  ],
  '4990a698-afba-483b-5544-ecc5201e45c3': [
    {
      doctor_id: '4990a698-afba-483b-5544-ecc5201e45c3',
      name: 'dr. Frank',
      specialization_id: '97ce4804-6508-4d65-dd33-70a3d14604ae',
      specialization_name: 'Neurologist',
      hospital_id: 'c279e92e-57c3-47ad-5656-397b4fe8b6f7',
      hospital_name: 'Hospital F',
      isExistSchedule: true
    }
  ]
}

let updatedDocs= Object.fromEntries(Object.entries({ ...doctors }).map(([key, value]) => ([key, [...value].filter(e => e.isExistSchedule)])).filter(e => e[1].length))

console.log(updatedDocs)
```

> Using simple `for-loop`

```
for (let doc in doctors) {
  let arr = [...doctors[doc].filter(item => item.isExistSchedule)];
  if(arr.length)
    UpdatedDocs[doc] = arr;
}

console.log(updatedDocs)
```

Comment: If array empty, I want to remove the parent too. So because `2bf169c6-bc51-4dc6-1234-cf81e611b6fd` have empty array, I want to remove it too

Comment: Okay thanks. I want to ask again. It makes a new loop? Can it be added to the existing loop? So no need to make a loop again. It p ossibility it will make a long process. Because a lot of looping

Comment: No, it's not a loop inside another one but serial, so It does not increases the complexity, however, yes you can put all the logic in a single loop.

Comment: What I mean is I already have this loop : `const newDoctors = {}
for (let item in doctors) {
  for (let i = 0; i < doctors[item].length; i++) {
    ...
  }
  newDoctors[item] = doctors[item]
}` Can the logic placed here?

Comment: From your code, I must make 2 loop like this : https://postimg.cc/jCPkmrp9. Can it be merged into one?

Comment: can you try merging it yourself and paste what didn't work? It's a straight forward merge.

Comment: Seems it can't be merged

Comment: It surely can be :)

Comment: It's complicated. If I use dummy data, it's easy. But I need the hospitalId and doctorId parameters to be sent to the API. From API, I get isExistScedule value. See comments on my code